# Proving that a set A in a metric space is bounded iff it belongs to a ball with radius r>0

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Prove that $A\subset X$ is bounded if and only if $A\subset B_r (a)$ for some $a\in X$ and $r>0.$
This is my own proof to the question.

Let $B_r(a)=\{x\in X : d(x_1,a)<r\}$ for some $a$ and $r>0$. Assuming that $A\subset B_r(a)$ implies that for any two points $x,y\in A$ we have that $d(x,a)<r,d(y,a)<r$. It follows that $$d(x,a)+d(y,a)<2r$$ $\forall x,y\in A.$  We also kmow since we have a metric space that $$d(x,a)+d(y,a)\geq d(x,y).$$
Thus we have $$sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\}=diamA\leq d(x,a)+d(y,a) <2r<\infty$$ $\forall x,y\in A$ which proves the result.

Is this proof correct? Awaiting your answer. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: yes, your answer is quite right.